# How does LU decomposition work?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm interested in the algorithm of LU decomposition in order to solve a LSE like $Ax=b$, where $A$ is a square matrix.

My question is: When I compute $PA=LU$ do I also need to interchange rows in $L$ whenever I interchange rows in $A$? It is clear, that I get $P$ by interchanging rows in $Id$ whenever I interchange rows in $A$, but is $L$ also affected?

Is it right that after that I need to solve $Lz = Pb$ and $Ux = z$?

Comment: Please stop deleting questions as soon as you receive an answer. And please abide by the honor policy of your school - i.e. don't cheat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve $Ax = b$, if $P A = LU$, then $LUx = Pb$:

a) compute $P A = LU$ factorization, saving $P$ info

b) solve $Ly = P b$, using forward substitution

c) solve $Ux = y$, using backward substitution.

Comment: okay, but how do I get $L$? I mean normally, without any pivoting you would just get it by writing down the factors when you substract one row from another. But in the case of pivoting, we interchange rows of $A$, do we also need to interchange rows of $L$ then?

Comment: https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs370/notes/LUExample2.pdf , this is also worth reviewing http://www4.ncsu.edu/~kksivara/ma505/handouts/lu-pivot.pdf